# What is the function of this query statement of sql

Tags: sql, alfresco

```
USE [DataStore]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_alf_cass_qnln] ON [dbo].[alf_child_assoc]
    (
    [parent_node_id] ASC,
    [qname_ns_id] ASC,
    [qname_localname] ASC,
    [qname_crc] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: It creates an index on table alf_child_assoc.

Answer (score 1):

It creates an nonclustered index.

Generally, nonclustered indexes are created to improve the performance of frequently used queries not covered by the clustered index or to locate rows in a table without a clustered index (called a heap). You can create multiple nonclustered indexes on a table or indexed view.